# Methods in the namespace System.Security.Cryptography take 2 minutes to perform when service is hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, delay

I built an ASP.NET web-service that uses the System.Security.Cryptography namespace when it handles its requests.

When I hosted the service in ASP.NET Development Server, everything worked fine.
Then I moved the service into IIS, still using localhost addresses, and surprisingly, each time the service calls a method from the specified namespace, it takes 2 minutes to complete! If a single request requires the service to call 3 methods of the specified namespace, then the request takes total of 6 minutes to complete!

The traces show that the request has been received on time, and they show an interval of around 2 minutes upon each call to the specified namespace.

Did anyone see this strange behavior elsewhere?
Any speculation would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you turned on "Load user profile" on the application pool?

Comment: Wow, you're good! The problem was indeed around this area of profile loading. It was set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. When changed it to anything else, the problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: Can I post this as an answer so you accept?

Comment: Of course. Post and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepcted answer would be : change the application's pool identity and check the "load user profile" so that cryptographic services can be used on behalf of app pool identity.